# How to porting Oracle stored procedures to Impala

Tags: stored-procedures, porting, impala

For example, the original SP include several IN parameters and SQLs. Now, I used java application which implemented each SQLs and used Oozie to simulate the whole process/workflow in Oracle SP, not sure if it is the right way. Could you please provide some advices?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CTE (Common Table Expressions) to model your queries. Stored procedures as database objects are not supported in Hive/Impala yet. You may want to have a look [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/v1/v1-1-1/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_langref_sql.html#with_unique_1)